# Hide hard drive in gnome-disk-utility

Tags: linux-mint, kde

I have installed the gnome-disk-utility which I'll be using to format USB sticks and SD Cards.

But it also shows both of my hard drives, which I don't want to be formatted.

Since I'm dealing with beginner users, I'd like to hide those partitions in order to prevent accidental formatting.

So, how do I do it? If it is possible, of course ;)

Oh, btw i'm using Linux Mint 17.1 KDE

Answer (score 1):

Three steps once you open gnome-disks using sudo "sudo gnome-disks"

1. Select the partition which you want to hide using the mouse.
2. Click on the "additional partition options" button (gears) below the "volumes" diagram and select "Edit Mount Options"
3. Turn off the show in user interface switch.
   Done!

[image: Step 1 and 2]
[image: Step 3]